# Swift iOS static uitableviewheader

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I wonder if its possible to add a static uitableviewheader? I want the header to look like an extension of the navigation bar. But I can't get it to work, my header keeps scrolling with the table view.

Comment: You will have to add the view(header) to the view which contains the table view. And make sure the scrol insects of the table view include the (header)view.

Comment: @rckoenes but is that possible with a tableview controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to change the frame of your UITableView to be smaller, and add a UIView above the table, outside of it. This way, the UIView will stay on the screen and the tableview will scroll beneath it. For example:

[image: UIView and UITableView]

Comment: Is this possible in a table view controller? In storyboard I can only add a view inside the table view in my table view controller

Comment: Hmm, this screenshot comes from a storyboard. If you start with a regular ViewController in the storyboard instead of a TableViewController, then add a UITableView to the ViewController, you should be able to accomplish this arrangement and modify the frame of the UITableView to make room for a UIView on top.